# drawing a diagram with JFreeChart

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jfreechart, diagram

I'm working with jFreeChart on Eclipse (in Windows) and I want to draw gantt diagram for processors.
I'm doing a  XY Chart

But my programme draw me a line with only P0. I want something like

- draw from 0 to 10 --> P0
- then from 10  to 20 --> draw H
- then from 20 to 30 ---->draw wait
- from 30 to 40---> draw P0
- from 35 to 40 -->draw H

Code:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
    import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
    import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

    public class JFreeChartLineChartExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JFreeChartLineChartExample(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {
    super(applicationTitle);

    // based on the dataset we create the chart
    JFreeChart pieChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(chartTitle, "Time", "Processors",    
      createDataset(),PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    // Adding chart into a chart panel
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(pieChart);

    // settind default size
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

    // add to contentPane
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {

  final XYSeries P0 = new XYSeries("P0");
  P0.add(0, 1);
  P0.add(10, 1);

  P0.add(35, 1);
  P0.add(50, 1);
  P0.add(85, 1);
  P0.add(110, 1);


  final XYSeries P2 = new XYSeries("P2");



  final XYSeries P1 = new XYSeries("P1");



  final XYSeries H = new XYSeries("H");
  H.add(10, 1);
  H.add(20, 1);
  H.add(45, 1);
  H.add(100, 1);


  final XYSeries wait = new XYSeries("wait");
  wait.add(80, 1);
  wait.add(90, 1);
  wait.add(105, 1);



  final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
  dataset.addSeries(P0);
  dataset.addSeries(P2);
  dataset.addSeries(P1);
  dataset.addSeries(H);
  dataset.addSeries(wait);

  return dataset;

       }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFreeChartLineChartExample chart = new JFreeChartLineChartExample(" GANTT ", " GANTT");
  chart.pack();
  chart.setVisible(true);
     }
   }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i execute my program i have a line (red line of only PO)                   what i want is fro 0 to 10 draw P0 with ( red line) then from 10 to 20 draw H for exemple with (blue line ) from 20 to 30 draw wait with (green line )

Comment: and then go back to P0 and draw it with red line from 30 to 400 for exemple

Comment: the problem is when i go back to P0 and try to draw it from 30 to 400 it start from 10 not from 30

Comment: is my question still not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood you want to have gaps in your datasets. Your code paints a straight line from time 0 to 110 for dataset P0 because JFreeChart does not know that you want to have gaps.

To add gaps you need to add `null` values to your datasets.

For example P0 should be created as follows:

```
final XYSeries P0 = new XYSeries("P0");
P0.add(0, 1);
P0.add(10, 1);
P0.add(11, null);
P0.add(35, 1);
P0.add(50, 1);
P0.add(51, null);
P0.add(85, 1);
P0.add(110, 1);
```

You might also have a look at the special Gantt classes provided by JFreeChart. There are some examples in the JFreeChart demo.

Comment: thank you i'm using gantt now thanks for the idea though